# What is PHP's equivalent of an ASP.NET MasterPage?

Tags: php, asp.net, master-pages

I am new to PHP.  How can I create a base (like an asp.net masterpage) and have all other pages inherit from the base page or designate that I want pages to inherit from a certain base page, so I don't have to recreate things like headers, navigation, footers, etc...

Is it just more or do ASP.NET Masterpages seem to slow things down and add unnecessary clutter?

Comment: If you use MVC frameworks like Codeigniter, Yii, etc it is possible to achieve similar results, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3208300/92487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in php; however, there are 2 functions you can use to simulate that.

`include()` and `require().`

Like this

top.php

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>google<title>
<!--css and script includes-->
</head>
        <body>
<div id="top">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a>link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Other.php

random text

The two constructs are identical in every way except how they handle failure. include() produces a Warning while require() results in a Fatal Error.

Comment: So I assume header.php would include markup for just a header and then I would put that in a header section for another page.  Is that correct?

Comment: What is the difference between include and require? and where would you put the stylesheet link for menu.php?

Comment: One thing I noticed in your example is that menu.php doesn't actually contain any php code, so could this just be an html file and in the Other.php file, I can do something like <?include ('menu.html') ?> or does it have to have the php extension.

Comment: @Xaisoft, you new best friend: http://php.net If you want to lookup a function's documentation: `http://php.net/[functionName]` for example http://php.net/require

Answer (score 2):

Php doesn't have masterpages.

You can however create functionality for them.
Its not exactly a master template tho

Here is a simple example:

header.php

```
<!doctype><html><head></head><body>
```

index.php

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?> // more html here // <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

footer.php

```
</body></html>
```

Comment: it seems simple to implement !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use a template engine which supports features like inheritance. Using plain PHP for templates is a PITA.

Twig looks pretty nice and supports template inheritance: http://www.twig-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what a masterpage should be - but normally your start with a single index.php, which includes all necessary libraries, files and also templates, which are used to format the output. To request a single page, normally you use a request-parameter on that index.php.

Answer (score -1):

There is a VERY nice way using functions:

```
ob_start();
ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

[See an example](http://spinningtheweb.blogspot.com.br/2006/07/approximating-master-pages-in-php.html)